# Calculating with Joint density

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, density-function

Given two random variables $X$ and $Y$ with the joint density

$$f(x,y) = axy \mathbb{1}_{\{X>0, Y>0, X+Y \leq 1\}},$$

how can one calculate the parameter $a$?

Comment: You should properly distinguish between capital $X$ and lower-case $x$. Otherwise things like $\Pr(X\le x)$ are incomprehensible, as are lots of other things involved. The density $f(x,y)$ is a function of $x$ and $y$, not of $X$ and $Y$. You should have $1_{\{x>0,\, y>0,\, x+y\le 1 \}}. \qquad$

Comment: You need  $\displaystyle \int\limits_\text{whole plane} f(x,y)\, d(x,y) = 1.$ If you find $\displaystyle \int\limits_\text{whole plane} f(x,y)\, d(x,y) = a \times \text{something},$ then you need $a\times\text{something} = 1,$ and from that you can find what $a$ is. Were you aware that that is what you need to do? If so, at what point did you run into difficulty doing it? $\qquad$

Comment: I have the problem with evaluating the integral...does the integral transform to $a \int_0^1 \int_0^1 xy dx dy$?

Comment: You should edit your question to say that that's the part you had difficulty with. Phrasing questions here in language suitable for assigning homework tends to be frowned on here, and that's probably why someone down-voted the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The integral over the region where $1_{\{x>0,\, y>0,\, x+y\le 1 \}}=0$ is $0$, so you just need to integrate over the region where $x>0,$ $y>0,$ and $x+y\le1.$ You can write
$$
\int_0^1 \cdots\cdots \,dx
$$
and then inside that you got an integral with respect to $y$.

For any fixed value of $x$ between $0$ and $1$, you have $y$ going from $0$ to $1-x,$ so that $x+y$ remains $\le 1.$  Thus you have
$$
\int_0^1 \left( \int_0^{1-x} \cdots\cdots \, dy  \right) dx.
$$
(And where the dots are you need $axy.$)

(You can also do it with the roles of $x$ and $y$ interchanged, getting $\displaystyle \int_0^1 \left( \int_0^{1-y}\cdots\cdots \, dx \right) dy$.)

Comment: Okay thank you, one more question regarding the marginal distribution $f_X$: For that I have to integrate the joint density w.r.t. $x$, i.e. $f_X(x) = \int_0^1 axy dy$, since $y$ can take a value between $0$ and $1$ right? Or is the upper boarder again $1-x$?

Comment: There you need $1-x$, for the same reason.